# Alignment of red dot (uniformity mark) on tire when no white dot or dimple

Tags: tires, wheels, wheel-balance, weight

I am new to tire markings, and have been reading what they mean.  However, there is not one clear source of information what to do when there is **no white dot/dimple on the rim** (marking the rim's lowest point).

There are two camps of thought:

---

**Camp 1: Ignore the red dot, align yellow dot**

[How to balance a tire properly: use the yellow and red dots](http://www.rtsauto.com/how-to-balance-a-tire-properly-use-the-yellow-and-red-dots/)

> Yellow and Red Dot: The red always takes priority if the rim has a
>   white dot or dimple; in such case align red to white. The white dot
>   indicates the low point for radial runout/radial force variation of
>   the rim.
>
> If there is no white dot or dimple forget the red dot and align the
>   yellow dot to the valve stem.

---

**Camp 2: Align red dot with valve stem**

[Do you know what those colored dots on the sides of new tires are for?](https://www.topgear.com.ph/features/tip-sheet/do-you-know-what-those-colored-dots-on-the-sides-of-new-tires-are-for-a2600-20181008)

> align the red dot with the mark on the wheel

...

> Now, if you have both red and yellow dots on your tire and you don't
>   have any dots or marks on your wheel, red takes precedence over yellow
>   and you should align the red dot with the valve stem.

[Are you seeing dots? Those color-coded sidewall markings serve a purpose](https://www.tirebusiness.com/article/20070813/ISSUE/308139967/are-you-seeing-dots-those-color-coded-sidewall-markings-serve-a-purpose)

> whenever you see a red spot, match this up with the valve stem-unless
>   you happen to have a steel wheel that has a dimple on the exterior
>   side of the rim area

[WHAT RED AND YELLOW DOT MEANS ON TIRES WHERE TO PUT RED DOT ON WHEEL](https://youtu.be/VRtOoxnR7C4?t=149) (video)

---

**Re-stating Question**

Thank you for reading.

What is the correct camp of thought?

---

**Bonus!**

Here is a question I can't find an article addressing.

If the tire only has a red dot (no yellow dot), what should one do?